# Proving the existence of a particular vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $F$ be a field and let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $F$. Assume that $\text{dim}_F(V) \ge 3$. Let $T$ be an invertible linear transformation. Let $u$ and $v$ be a pair of linearly independent vectors. Finally, assume that $T(u) = v$.

We wish to show that there exists a vector $w \in V$ such that the vectors $u$, $v$, and $w$ are linearly independent and $T(w) \notin Fv + Fw$.

Here's my approach. Since nothing is really standing out on how to `find' this vector, I decided to aim for a contradiction. So, let's assume that whenever $w \in V$ is a vector that is linearly independent with $u$ and $v$, then $T(w) \in Fv + Fw$.

Take the set $\{ u, v\}$ and complete it to a basis for $V$ over $F$, say $\{ u ,v, w_1, \ldots, w_k\}$. (Note that since $V$ has dimension at least $3$, we know that $k \ge 1$.) By our assumption, $T(w_i) \in Fv + Fw_i$ for each $i =1,\ldots, k$. Thus, $\{T(w_1), \ldots, T(w_k)\}$ is a set of linearly independent vectors that are contained in the hyperplane $U = Fv + Fw_1 + \cdots + Fw_k$. (The linear independence follows from the invertibility of $T$.) Of course, $v \in U$. Thus $\{v ,T(w_1), \ldots, T(w_k)\}$ is basis for $U$. I was originally trying to argue that $u \in U$, which would yield a contradiction. But no luck. I think I can prove that $T(v) \in Fu$ though. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k$ be the smallest non-negative integer such that $\{T^i u: 0\le i \le k\}$ are linearly dependent.

If $k\ge 4$ then you're done, because then $u=T^0 u, v = T^1 u, T^2 u, T^3 u$ are linearly independent.  You can take $w=T^2 u$ then $Tw = T^3 u\not\in\operatorname{span}\{v,w\}$ due to the linear independence.

Since $u=T^0 u, v=T^1 u$ are assumed linearly independent the remaining cases are $k=2$ and $k=3$ which can be handled by looking at matrices.

For $k=3$, let $w=T^2 u = Tv$.  The space $V'=\operatorname{span}\{u, v, w\}$ is invariant under $T$ ($TV'\subseteq V'$).  The matrix for $T$ on $V'$ has the form
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & a\\
1 & 0 & b\\
0 & 1 & c
\end{pmatrix}$$
From the invertability of $T$ it follows that $a\ne 0$ so $Tw\not\in\operatorname{span}\{v,w\}$ as required.

For $k=2$, the space $V'=\operatorname{span}\{u,v\}$ is invariant under $T$.  The matrix for $T$ on $V'$ has the form
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a\\
1 & b\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
From the invertability of $T$ it follows that $a\ne 0$.  Since the dimension of $V$ is $\ge 3$, there is some $w\not\in V'$.  If $Tw$ happens to be in $\operatorname{span}\{v,w\}$, then $T(w+v)$ is not, and the vectors $\{u, v, w+v\}$ are linearly independent.